# How can I pre-populate a lookup field in lightning:inputField?

Tags: lightning

I have been trying to pre-populate a lookup based lightning:inputField with a default value.

The code below renders a lookup field that works but I would like to be able to set a default contact in the field when it renders on the page.  I have tried a lot of different ways to get this to go, but am at a loss.  Any ideas?

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="ContactId" aura:id="contactId"/>
```

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please post your code? As I am trying to implement the lightning:inputField, i.e. lookup field, I am getting a input box with a spinner right next to the magnifying glass(search).

Comment: This is basically it.

<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes">
     <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Case">
    <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="ContactId" aura:id="input_field" value="0033D00000ONAN3"/>
    <lightning:button  variant="brand" class="btn" type="submit" label="Create" />
</lightning:recordEditForm>    
</aura:component>

Comment: I tried to see if I can get a OOB lookup from Salesforce. Because, previously I have created a Custom Lookup. For now, I have just created a sample lightning component by reference this: [lightning:inputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputField.htm). I got a search box with a spinner right next to it.

Comment: Do you have any of your code to share?

Answer (score 1):

Use on load event :

Try to set your input field value in client side controller.

({
    handleCreateLoad: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var nameFieldValue = cmp.find("input_field").set("v.value", "your ID here");
    }
})

Answer (score 0):

You can use `value` attribute to set a default value.

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="ContactId" aura:id="contactId" value="00222Ayqz"/>
```

Source:

- [Lightning Web Components: Input Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputField/documentation)

Comment: That was the first thing that I tried.  I tried both the 15 and 18 character ID of the contact that I wanted to default it to.  Unfortunately that did not work.